# Is it a bad idea to check whether malloc was successful using a user-defined function?

Tags: c, malloc

When using malloc in C, I'm always told to check to see if any errors occurred by checking if it returned a NULL value. While I definitely understand why this is important, it is a bit of a bother constantly typing out 'if' statements and whatever I want inside them to check whether the memory was successfully allocated for each individual instance where I use malloc. To make things quicker, I made a function as follows to check whether it was successful.

```
#define MAX 25
char MallocCheck(char* Check);
char *Option1, *Option2;
int main(){
    Option1 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX);
    MallocCheck(Option1);
    Option2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX);
    MallocCheck(Option2);
    return 0;
}

char MallocCheck(char* Check){
    if(Check == NULL){
        puts("Memory Allocation Error");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

However, I have never seen someone else doing something like this no matter how much I search so I assume it is wrong or otherwise something that shouldn't be done.

Is using a user-defined function for this purpose wrong and if so, why is that the case?

Comment: Why not code a safe malloc wrapping malloc AND check?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre - I'm sorry but I don't fully understand so you'll have to bear with me. Do you mean putting the part where I check for NULL in the same line as where I allocate the memory with something like:
If(Option2 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX) == NULL)

Comment: It's not a great idea to dump error messages to `stdout`, that's what `stderr` is for. Replace the `puts()` with `perror()`, get a meaningful, human readable reason for the error for free.

Comment: @Saser Jean possibly meant to use `void* myMalloc(size_t size) { void* ptr = malloc(size); if (!ptr) { puts("Memory Allocation Error"); exit(1);} return ptr;}` instead of `malloc()` followed by `MallocCheck()` everytime

Comment: I do the same as well, I find it a bit annoying to repeat my self ... The only downside in my opinion is the cost of calling the function but since optimisation is not my main concern I don't find that an issue.

Comment: @Serge I'm still completely sure, but if I understand correctly that function you gave checks if the memory was allocated successfully while also allowing you to specify how much memory you want to allocate?

Comment: Aside from issues like `MallocCheck()` having a return type but no return statement, etc.  the idea of checking the result with your own function is okay... but it only makes sense if you're always going to handle the error the same way.  Also, be aware that on many systems `malloc()` may allocate memory optimistically -- in which case it may succeed even when memory is low, with an error only showing up when you write to the memory block before enough free memory becomes available.

Comment: In programs used by your clients, a "Sorry" message followed by a sharp exit with no clean-up might be easy for you, and more polite than "segfault", but you really need an alternate strategy. Making your program robust and responsive to both internal and operational problems, is what will make your program a success, as opposed to one whose users will throw in the bin.

Comment: @Weather Vane On memory allocation errors, there are usually not very much options how to continue.  E.g. when `malloc()` (for small sizes) fails, subsequent `malloc()` in error paths (`printf()` in stdio streams) will fail very likely too.  So, an `abort()` on allocation errors of "normal" heap objects is ok;  expensive error handling makes sense for large buffers only.

Comment: @ensc abort (and a restart if embedded) is a *last resort* in a commercial app, and should be used to give the developer as much info as possible, where the problem ocurred, and why. This supposed time-saver might be useful when developing, but my point was you need a better clean-up strategy before "drop and run", such as flushing buffers and closing files. You have to at least *try* rather than just saying "oh I probably can't clean up" and giving up.

Answer (score 1):

Error checking is a *good* thing.

Making a helper function to code quicker, better is a *good* thing.

The details depend on coding goals and your group's coding standards.

OP's approach is not bad.  I prefer to handle the error with the allocation.  The following outputs on `stderr` [@EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427945/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-check-whether-malloc-was-successful-using-a-user-defined-fun#comment66179482_39427945) and does not complain of a `NULL` return when 0 bytes allocated (which is not a out-of-memory failure).

```
void *malloc_no_return_on_OOM(size_t size) {
  void *p = mallc(size);
  if (p == NULL && size > 0) {
    // Make messages informative
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc(%zu) failure\n", size);
    // or 
    perror("malloc() failure");
    exit(1);
  }
  return p;
}
```

Advanced: Could code a `DEBUG` version that contains the callers function  and line by using a macro.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addendum to @chux's answer and the comments.

As stated, DRY code is generally a good thing and `malloc` errors are often handled the same way within a specific implementation.

It's true that some systems (notably, Linux) offer optimistic `malloc` implementations, meaning `malloc` always returns a valid pointer (never `NULL`) and the error is reported using a signal the first time data is written to the returned pointer... which makes error handling slightly more complex then the code in the question.

**However**, moving the error check to a different function might incur a performance penalty, unless the compiler / linker catches the issue and optimizes the function call away.

This is a classic use case for inline functions (on newer compilers) or macros.

i.e.

```
#include <signal.h>

void handle_no_memory(int sig) {
  if (sig == SIGSEGV) {
    perror("Couldn't allocate or access memory");
    /* maybe use longjmp to stay in the game...? Or not... */
    exit(SIGSEGV);
  }
}

/* Using a macro: */
#define IS_MEM_VALID(ptr)                                                      \
  if ((ptr) == NULL) {                                                         \
    handle_no_memory(SIGSEGV);                                                 \
  }
/* OR an inline function: */
static inline void *is_mem_valid(void *ptr) {
  if (ptr == NULL)
    handle_no_memory(SIGSEGV);
  return ptr;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  /* consider setting a signal handler - `sigaction` is better, but I'm lazy. */
  signal(SIGSEGV, handle_no_memory);
  /* using the macro */
  void *data_macro = malloc(1024);
  IS_MEM_VALID(data_macro);
  /* using the inline function */
  void *data_inline = is_mem_valid(malloc(1024));
}
```

Both macros and inline functions prevent code jumps and function calls, since the `if` statement is now part of the function instead of an external function.

When using `inline`, the compiler will take the assembly code and place it within the function (instead of performing a function call). For this, we must trust the compiler to so it's job properly (it usually does it's job better than us).

When using macros, the preprocessor takes care of things and we don't need to trust the compiler.

In both cases the function / macro is local to the file (notice the `static` key word), allowing any optimizations to be performed by the compiler (not the linker).

Good luck.